# Convert Jagged Array to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this Jagged Array  :

(`n` is given at compile time , so please assume that all values are already there)

```
int[][] jagged = new int[n][];

jagged[0] = new int[3];
jagged[0][0] = 2; // Please ignore the dummy values....
jagged[0][1] = 55;
jagged[0][2] = 4;

jagged[1] = new int[3];
jagged[1][0] = 6;
jagged[1][1] = 3;
jagged[1][2] = 7;

...
...
jagged[n] = new int[3];
jagged[n][0] = 9;
jagged[n][1] = 5;
jagged[n][2] = 1;
```

I want to create a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>>` from this structure where :

**key** is : `dummy value` and the **value** is the `n` ( dummy value is unique)

*(aside info - I need to map pictures to users)*

So for group `#1` I want:

```
  {2-> 0}
  {55-> 0}
  {4-> 0}
```

for group `#2`

```
  {6 -> 1}
  {3-> 1}
  {7-> 1}
  ...
  ...
  etc
```

But as a whole list :

So final result should be 1 `IEnumerable` of `KeyValuePair<int,int>`:

```
  {2-> 0}
  {55-> 0}
  {4-> 0}
  {6 -> 1}
  {3-> 1}
  {7-> 1}
  ...
  {9 -> n}
  {5-> n}
  {1-> n}
```

**Question :**

- Is there any Linq'y way of doing it ?(instead of loops over loops ) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
foreach (var t in jagged.SelectMany((row, rowIndex) => row.Select(value => new KeyValuePair<int, int>(value, rowIndex))))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", t.Key, t.Value);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but producing the desired result as a temp expression in a foreach() isn't optimal.

Comment: Everything you need is in that answer. Just assign the query into variable instead of using it in `foreach` loop directly and you're good to go.